# Integral of $\frac{x}{ax^2+b}$

Tags: integration

I would like some advice as to how I should go about integrating the following function in the most efficient way.

The function is $$\frac{x}{ax^2+b}$$

I know what the answer is $$[\frac{1}{2a}ln(b+ax^2)]+c$$

I know this by seeing a rule for it somewhere but I would like to know the workings behind the rule.
Thanks.

Comment: You have a superb typo in the answer you give ! I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If $a=0$ then
  $$\int \frac1b xdx=\frac1{2b}x^2+C$$
- If $a\ne0$ then
  $$\int\frac{xdx}{ax^2+b}=\frac1{2a}\int\frac{2axdx}{ax^2+b}=\frac1{2a}\ln(|ax^2+b|)+C$$

Comment: Excellent Thank you very much.

Comment: Excellent, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not correct.

With $a\ne 0$, let $ax^2+b=z^2$, then the integral becomes $$\int \frac{z}{az^2}dz=\frac{1}{2a}\ln(|ax^2+b|)+c$$.

Comment: Samrat, the typo has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

let 
$ax^2+b=z $ and If $a\ne0$ then 
$$\frac{dz}{dx}= 2ax$$
so $$x dx =\frac{dz}{2a}$$ 
So the given integration become 
$$\int \frac{dz}{2a z}$$
We know that $$\int \frac{dx}{x}=ln|x| +c $$
so $$\int \frac{dz}{2a z}=\frac{ln|z|}{2a}+c$$
So answer is $$\frac{ln| ax^2 + b| }{2a} +c$$
if a = 0
then integration become $$\int \frac{xdx}{b}$$
so the answer is $$\frac{x^2}{2b}+c$$